# Disabling the layout

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am new to ZF2. I created one application based on the zf2 tutorial. In that i have layout.phtml in Application/view/layout folder and this is the header and footer in it aling with the content.Is there any function like for disabling my layout without the content.

Answer (score 2):

In the controller's action where you want to disable the layout use the below code:

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
$viewModel->setTerminal(true);
return $viewModel;
```

This will return only viewpart without layout.

For more check [this link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html).

Answer (score 0):

To disable the layout of an action and to set a different view template for an action

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
$viewModel->setTemplate('application/view.phtml');
$viewModel->setTerminal(true);
return $viewModel;
```

this may help you!